# Difference between base_url scenarios

Tags: css, codeigniter, base-url

I am a bit confuse about the difference between the two url scenarios like

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/blabla';

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(). 'css/style.css'; ?>" />
```

If I will set the base_url() as on the first given the site would apply the css but if I set it to the second given example the css would not apply and the browser logs could not found(404) but it has the same generated url like

```
localhost/blabla/css/style.css
```

WHY? i am reading the documentation in elislab website but cant figure it out. Any input guys..

Answer (score 0):

```
 $config['base_url'] = '';
 $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/blabla';
```

Try this, should work for the both above:

```
<?php
    $this->load->helper('url');
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: I had autoloaded the url helper in the config

Comment: hmm i just coded to test this and it works fine. Where did you put your css folder and what is the exact url used?